# Java Regex to extract numbers and strings from a string

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to extract numbers and strings from a string.

Ex.

> "TU111 1998 SUMMER”
>
> "TU-232 SU 1999"
>
> "TU232 1999 SUMMER"

I was able to get it using two patterns `Pattern.compile("\\d+")` and `Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+")`
Is there a way to get it using one pattern?

The expected outcome should be

> 1=>TU 2=> 111/232 3=>1998/1999 4=>SUMMER/SU

Comment: Can you give the expected outcome for each of your input cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just *pipe* the two regexes together:

`[0-9]+|[a-zA-Z]+`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1RiXZW/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try with this.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\d+)|([a-zA-Z]+))");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("TU111 1998 SUMMER");
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey you have to use 2 regexes  [a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+ and maybe the different code I wrote below might give you a hint.just updating Pattern.compile() and string will be enough.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(,\\d+)*?\\.?\\d+?");
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = p.matcher("your string");
    while (m.find()) {  
        numbers.add(m.group());
    }   
    System.out.println(numbers);
```